# Can I use Sparkfun Schematic/Layout in my design?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, eaglecad, open-source

I am currently working on my thesis project (PCB designing) where I want to use some components on my PCB such as antenna and ublox NEO D9S chip. There is a company called Sparkfun, who makes PCBs based on chip ublox NEO D9S and have provided schematic/layout for their PCB online.

- On Wikipedia, it says that Sparkfun is an open source hardware company so in this case, I want to know if I can use their layout to create similar connections for my thesis or not?
- I want to copy their layout and make adaptation to them for my thesis. Is this allowed or is it not allowed?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "allowed". You **must** properly indicate that you copied the design and layout in your thesis, even if it is legal to do so. Don't try to take credit for work that someone else did.

Answer (score 10):

Sparkfun licences this design under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). This means you can "copy and adapt" the design, even for commercial use. The restrictions are you must *attribute* the design (as you would have to anyway for an academic project), and you must also redistribute your changes under the same licence.